# Detect finger touches movement on AppleWatch

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit, ios8.2

I want to detect touches on AppleWatch to get touch location. As we can achieve this behaviour on iPhone app by using following delegate methods:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //Any Logic
}
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //Any Logic
}
```

So, i just used these methods on WatchKit but not working;
Any way to achieve this behaviour?

I want to make some logic on the basis of touch location on WatchKit.

Any direction of work will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment (I don't know if things change in the future), there are no touch recognisers like that for WatchKit. You can just respond on taps on buttons or a menu with a selector.

Comment: Alright; It should be available; May be in future Apple with expose it.
So, is it possible to get frame of any component? like WKInterfaceButton, WKInterfaceImage, etc? As we not have frame property like self.btn.frame;
Any way to get it?

Comment: I don't think that you can.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no getters for any WK UI objects.